# How to post Tweets with the Twitter API V2 in PHP?

Tags: php, twitter

I'm trying to post tweets with the Twitter API v2 but have an error. I'm using the TwitterAPIExchange.php library, this works fine when I'm trying to search for Tweets for example with GET. But no luck with POST, see code below also the Manage Tweets doc from Twitter: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/manage-tweets/api-reference/post-tweets

Maybe I'm missing some parameters after the end point.

```
header('Content-Type:application/json');

include ($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/TwitterAPIExchange.php");
 
$settings = array(
    'oauth_access_token' => "xxxx",
    'oauth_access_token_secret' => "xxxx",
    'consumer_key' => "xxxx",
    'consumer_secret' => "xxxx"
    
);

$url = "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets";
$requestMethod = 'POST';

$postfields = array('status' => 'This is the text to Tweet');

$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$response = $twitter->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)->setPostfields($postfields)->performRequest();
```

**Errors:**

```
{
errors: [
{
parameters: { },
message: "Requests with bodies must have content-type of application/json."
}
],
title: "Invalid Request",
detail: "One or more parameters to your request was invalid.",
type: "https://api.twitter.com/2/problems/invalid-request"
}
```

Comment: Error message tells you to add header Content-Type: application/json

Comment: Thanks, is the header in the code not correct?

Comment: No, of course it isn't - that sets the Content-Type header for the response of _your_ script, it has nothing whatsoever to do with what is send in the request to the twitter API. You need to go and check whether your library you are using there supports specifying the Content-Type for the API request somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the Abraham\TwitterOAuth library instead and was able to send a tweet from the tutorial on this page:
https://artisansweb.net/tweet-twitter-php/

Comment: this API no longer seems to work